# Using fibers for evented iteration?

Tags: ruby

As part of my CS education, I am in the process of building a multiplayer Android yatzy game with clients linked together by a TCP server based on Ruby/EventMachine with JSON messages representing game events passed back and forth.

However, I'm feeling uncertain about how to optimally handle game turn management.

A typical yatzy game consists of 15 rounds. My implementation will handle up to 4 players. Events like dice rolls, dice holds and score choices are sent to the Ruby server and broadcast to the other players.

Currently, my server is handling game turns. Each time it receives a new score choice from a client, it broadcasts the score to the other clients. Subsequently it broadcasts a message with the user id of the next player to roll the dice.

I would like my system to be able to handle players dropping out without ending the game for the remaining players as a grim side effect. I've come up with a solution, but I'm not confident that it's ideal.

```
@turnfiber = Fiber.new do
  15.times do
    @players.each do |key, value|
      Fiber.yield value
    end
  end
end
```

`@turnfiber` is an instance variable belonging to a game object which represents the running game. `@players` is a hash which uses the players' unique id's as keys and the corresponding player object as value.

`@turnfiber.resume` is called each time a turn has ended (through a score choice submission) to retrieve the next player to roll the dice and broadcast his permission to roll. The idea is that if a player leaves the game in say turn 4, his client will send a quit message that will remove the leaving player from the `@players` hash, broadcast his departure, and because the player no longer resides in the `@players` hash, prevent succeeding iterations from handing dice control to the "dead" player thereby avoiding a deadlock. So far my Android client is incomplete, so I have not yet tested if this theory actually works in practice.

My choice of the Fiber class is based on a desire to be able to iterate 15 times over the `@players` and have them roll the dice one at a time. Fibers makes this possible since they pause the loop each time `yield` is called and returns the player.

I would like your thoughts about this approach, particularly what weaknesses it has and what alternatives you think I should consider to solve this problem of turn management.

Comment: It looks like the fiber is not retaining any state between resumes - in fact, it looks like you are deliberately mutating it over the fiber's lifetime (the @players variable).  Given that the only real advantage of a fiber over a simple in-line iterator is the persistence of the stack context, why use a fiber at all here?  You'll still need to block (or hand off to EventMachine's reactor) in the code using the fiber's yielded value, anyway.  I'm sure this approach will work fine and all, but I can't see it resulting in simpler code for this application.  Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Thinking about it, what I want is to do a nested iteration (15 rounds, 2-4 players) with the possibility of mutating the players variable and most importantly: Not do the iteration all at once, but one at a time.

I thought about using a round counter for the outer loop, but I will still need a way to iterate the players hash one at a time.

In Java, which I have worked with previously, one can retrieve an iterator object on collections and do calls to `next()` to retrieve the next object.

Is there something similar for Ruby?

Comment: I posted an answer to address your comment and original post.  I like this question, coroutines are a fascinating topic for discussion and are often misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has [Enumerators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html), which are a limited form of coroutines.  They work like this:

```
infinite_set = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  i = 0
  loop do
    yielder.yield(i += 1)
  end
end

puts infinite_set.next
puts infinite_set.next
puts infinite_set.next

# Output:
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Enumerators allow external iteration, lazy evaluation of lists, and multiple entry/exit points for a function.  If you look under the hood, you will see that Ruby implements them using fibers.

My take on your original code is that you want something like this:

```
(1..15).each do |round|
  # round code
  players.each do |player|
    next unless player.active?
    # do network IO with the player object
    # if the player times out or drops, change the player active state
  end
end
```

I think that adding another fiber to this adds unnecessary complexity unless your server is running several games concurrently, or needs some kind of in-process background queuing.  In that case, fibers and Eventmachine would be great.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your enumerator example, but I'm not sure about the second example. To me it looks like it's executing all at once and just breaking iteration of players that have dropped out.

The server in question should indeed have the capability of hosting multiple games concurrently, which is why I'm using EventMachine to avoid blocking code and threading.

Comment: I have wrapped your code inside an enumerator now (perhaps you were sugggesting that implicitly) and called `Yielder.yield` at the end of each iteration. It seems to work as well.

Comment: One more question, according to [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) the enumerator will raise a StopIteration exception that must be rescued. From what I can tell from the RubyDocs, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of Fiber's `alive?`, can you confirm that? The only way to handle this is by rescueing StopIteration or knowing how many times to call `next` in advance?

Comment: Yes, the entire construct would need to wrapped in a fiber for concurrency so that the fiber's scope includes the round counter for each game.  I'm guessing it's OK to block the fiber on network IO for each player (that is, each game does not background process anything during a player's turn).

Comment: That's the downside to using Enumerators, the only way to detect the end of one is to catch that StopIteration.  That's why you don't often see them used for finite lists, as an Array or Set is more appropriate when iterating over every element.  Their potential for lazy eval is their strength.